# Multi language software to run on two platforms

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, fonts

i had developed application in ubuntu using eclipse platform .i used our local language as displaying in gui forms.i used JLabel b = new JLabel("fonts of local lanuage(gujarati)");
i works properly in ubuntu but when i run this on windows it wont show properly means it displays like [][][][][][][].how to correct it.plz help me.

Comment: You probably need UTF8 encoding and fonts.

Comment: how is loaded this Font, UTF-8 isn't an issue in the case that glyps are correctly dispayed on another Native OS

Answer (score 0):

That may refer to Font. make sure you have fonts available in windows.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html) is a link to a `unicode` to `un-unicode` converter. it may be useful

Answer (score 0):

Yep the problem that you are facing is the font that is why when you run on windows it comes up like this

[][][][][][][]. The simplest solution to this is use a font native to windows such as Arial or Times New Roman.